# Error in using Wiki Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia-api

I was trying to follow one of the tutorials to fetch data from Wikipedia on my web page, but I am not sure why it is not working. I am fairly new to using APIs and jQuery. Here is the simple HTML page-

```
<html><head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="wikiscript.js"></script></head>

<body>
    <div id="wikiInfo"> &nbsp; </div>
</body><html>
```

Here is my wikiscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=google&prop=text&format=json&callback=?', function(json) { 
$('#wikiInfo').html(json.parse.text['*']); 
$("#wikiInfo").find("a:not(.references a)").attr("href", function(){ return "http://www.wikipedia.org" + $(this).attr("href");}); 
$("#wikiInfo").find("a").attr("target", "_blank");   }); });
```

The console gives me this error -

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at wikiscript.js:1

One of the problems possible is -

I have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded, and as such, before jQuery is fully loaded.

However, since I have no other scripts , could someone please guide me what to do.

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library. You have no jQuery library linked in the source code shown above.... remeber to include it before wikiscript. **Order matters**

Comment: "I have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded, and as such, before jQuery is fully loaded." Exactly. You need to include the jQuery library before running your code.

Comment: Could you please tell me exactly what to change/add. Kind of new at all of this.
i HAVE ADDED THIS - <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: That addition should have solved the error you had, on condition that you've added it BEFORE the <script> tag that you already had.